# How can I use the magick package in R to add a feather around the edge of an image?

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have a gif file I'm reading into R using the magick package, and I want to blur, or add a feathering effect to, the image edges of each frame. I see that this is possible in ImageMagick from the documentation (e.g. https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#distance_feather and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#vignette) but can't figure out how to translate this info into R. Which magick function(s) and parameters do I need to use to make this happen?

I know that I will need to work with each frame of the gif individually, e.g.:

```
img <- image_read("myGif.gif")

featheredGif <- _____ # ????insert a function to feather edges, applied to img[1]

for(i in 2:length(img)){
  featheredFrame <- _____ # ???? insert function to feather edges, applied to img[i]
  featheredGif <- c(featheredGif, featheredFrame)
}
```

I want the result to look similar to this https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/soft_edge.png or this https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/rose_feathered.png, though applied to every frame in the gif.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I do not know RMagick or R. But here are ImageMagick CLI commands for drawing an elliptical feathering and a round rectangle feathering.

Input:

[image]

Oval:

```
Read the image
Clone it and use -vignette to draw an ellipse and extract the alpha channel, blur it, then apply -level
Then put the result into the alpha channel of the input image

convert thumbnail.gif \
\( -clone 0 -background none -virtual-pixel none -vignette 0x0+0+0 \
-alpha extract -blur 0x10 -level 50x100% \) \
-alpha off -compose copyopacity -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

Round Rectangle:

```
Read the input image and get the bottom right corner coordinate   
Read it again. 
Clone it, fill it with black, draw a round rectangle, blur it, apply -level
Then put the result into the alpha channel of the input image

wm1=`convert thumbnail.gif -format "%[fx:w-1]" info:`
hm1=`convert thumbnail.gif -format "%[fx:h-1]" info:`
convert thumbnail.gif \
\( -clone 0 -fill black -colorize 100 \
-fill white -virtual-pixel black -draw "roundrectangle 0,0 $wm1,$hm1 15,15" \
-blur 0x10 -level 50x100% \) \
-alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite \
result2.png
```

[image]

So you need the RMagick equivalents of -vignette, -composite, -draw, -blur and -level.

Comment: Thanks for outlining how to do this in ImageMagick. I'm hoping someone can help me translate this into R, as well.